# When to use bokeh-server --script <file.py>?

Tags: python, bokeh

Looking at some of the Bokeh examples I see two different patterns.

1. For running [`taylor_server.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/glyphs/taylor_server.py) one proceeds as follows:

   Start `bokeh-server` and **separately** invoke python `taylor_server.py`
2. For running the [`stock_app.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/stock_applet/stock_app.py), one just does the following:

   Invoke `bokeh-server --script stock_app.py`

What is the difference? When should one use one interface or the other?

Answer (score 2):

Using `--script` allows you to create a responsive "app" that runs directly in the `bokeh-server`. This has some advantages, namely better callback handling and less network data transfer. You can also write regulars scripts (or use the ipython notebook) to power responsive pages with widgets, etc. but this will require sending data to and from your process to the `bokeh-server` and also as of Bokeh 0.7.1 the only mechanism to trigger callbacks is polling. (This will be improved in future releases, however.)